# Flutter create youtube player preview template with image and icon

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart, flutter-layout

I have like this code to build youtube player thumbnail with icon:

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: NetworkImage(
                "https://img.youtube.com/vi/_uOgXpEHNbc/0.jpg"),
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
    ),
    Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Center(
        child: Icon(
          Icons.smart_display,
          color: Colors.red,
          size: 100.0,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

This is result of code:

[image]

How to make sure that the transparent background of the picture does not affect the central icon? I just need the icon to stay light.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to keep white color of the Play icon in the center then you can try like this

```
Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: NetworkImage(
                    "https://img.youtube.com/vi/_uOgXpEHNbc/0.jpg"),
                fit: BoxFit.fill),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.7),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 50,
              width: 60,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          child: Center(
            child: Icon(
              Icons.smart_display,
              color: Colors.red,
              size: 100.0,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

[image: This is the output]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.7)` inside your parent container so it will affect only your parent. You can try [here](https://dartpad.dev/26c1df2680c33853908f2dcd6e784a42?null_safety=true)

```
return Center(
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Center(
        child: Container(
          height: 200,
          width: 200,
          decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            image: new DecorationImage(
              image: new NetworkImage(
                  'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRVuX218dvGRwSyGhdr1KeTrN6wocBci6xWWQ&usqp=CAU'),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: Container(
            color: Color(0xFF000000).withOpacity(0.7),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Container(
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                  "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTRtN8lufTjm-VwUnxm5uAwsW5dCrZqzFFWxg&usqp=CAU"),
            ),
            iconSize: 80,
            splashColor: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

I use the worst possible images to showcase the example. Don't mind

Output [image]